# The roundabout ... may have a sloped curb to allow more room for larger commercial vehicles

Tags: untagged

How does the roundabout having a sloped curb allow more room for larger commercial vehicles?

"[The roundabout has been designed with a tighter curve around the island to encourage lower speeds and may have a sloped curb to allow more room for larger commercial vehicles.](https://www.alberta.ca/traffic-circles-and-roundabouts.aspx)"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to a vertical curb, a sloped curb can more easily be driven over or surmounted without wheel, tire, or chassis damage.

This is likely of greater importance to larger (i.e., "commercial") vehicles, which because of their greater size will have less clearance to fit between the curbs on either side of the street. In addition, larger vehicles' greater length will bring the vehicles' rear wheels closer to the curb on the inside of a roundabout.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!